# How many comments does it take to show the "show x more comments" thing

Tags: support, comments

I often see posts with a lot of comments. Sometimes I see only few comments then I see the "show x more comment" link. But sometimes I see loads of comments before the link.

Is this behavior random or does it depends on something? My guess is that it checks the "degree of chatty ness". When it becomes more chatty, it shows more comments. But that sounds unpractical.

Comment: It's somewhat based on comment votes. If there are a lot of upvoted comments, there will be a lot of displayed comments.